# Sencha Touch 2 Component in list emptyText

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list component that I want to display a button to send a suggestion for the data to be included if it turns up no results.

List component itself is implemented like this:

```
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemTpl: '{name}',

            // This is not ideal!
            emptyText: [
                '<div class="x-button-normal x-button">',
                    '<span class="x-button-label">',
                        'Suggest <i><span id="suggest-name"></i>',
                    '</span>',
                '</div>'
            ].join(''),

            store: 'TheStore'
        }
```

And this is the handler for the search field that simply sets a substring filter on the store:

```
        'keyup': function(self, e, eOpts) {
            queryString = self.getValue();
         
            var store = Ext.getStore('TheStore');
            store.clearFilter();
         
            if(queryString){
                var thisRegEx = new RegExp(queryString, "i");
                store.filterBy(function(record) {
                    if (thisRegEx.test(record.get('name'))) {
                        return true;
                    };
                    return false;
                });
                // Changes the button so it shows name
                document.getElementById('suggest-name').innerText = queryString;
            }
        },
```

Right now, I have the emptyText set to some simple HTML that emulates the look of a Sencha Touch button, but this means I have none of the button behaviour since it's not tied into the component system (such as being depressed when tapped). How can I set the emptyText attribute (or emulate it) since a proper button is displayed instead?

Comment: Have you seen this thread on the Sencha forum? It talks about rendering components inside a List (well, technically a ComponentView). http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161461-Render-components-inside-list

Answer (score 1):

Try to view the two screencasts below

- [Sencha Touch - Intro to Nested List Component](http://vimeo.com/20580117)
- [Sencha Touch 2 -
  Intro to List Component](http://vimeo.com/37212149)

Comment: Neither of those videos address my situation.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's about 2 years too late... but I ran into the same problem as @Hampus Nilsson and when I found the solution, I figured if I was running into this 2 years later, others might run into it as well.

With that said... I'm currently running **Sencha Touch version 2.3.1**.  The solution, as it pertains to that version, was really easy to implement, just super tricky to find.  The problem is that Sencha has a CSS property on the emptyText component (x-list-emptytext class) that is ignoring all pointer interactions called `pointer-events: none;`  (who knew?!)

This property is found in:

*[sdk_root]/resources/themes/stylesheets/sencha-touch/base/src/dataview/_List.scss*

```
.x-list-emptytext {
        text-align: center;
        pointer-events: none;  // THIS ONE!!
        font-color: #333333;
        @include st-box();
        @include st-box-orient(vertical);
        @include st-box-pack(center);
}
```

To fix this, simply override that property in your own sass/css.  I chose to override it with `pointer-events: inherit;` but your mileage may vary.

**THEN**, all you need to do is setup a listener on your list, *I recommend in the initialize function of your list class*, like the so:

```
this.emptyTextCmp.element.on({
    delegate: '.x-button-normal',
    scope: this,
    tap: this.yourCustomFunction
});
```

Where `this` is your list component.  It's important to note that you need a "." in front of the class name of your delegate.  In the above example, I set the delegate to: '.x-button-normal', because that was one of the two classes listed in the question's code.  I could've also used '.x-button'.  **If it were me**, I'd give your html an additional class, to be used as the delegate, that helps identify it a little better, instead of just using the default Sencha class as your delegate.  That's an opinion, not a requirement.

That's it, I hope this helps someone else!